# ubuntu use proxy for whole network traffic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, socks-proxy

How to set ubuntu to use a proxy (socks 5) for whole applications traffic?

I tried proxychains, but it only works for one app, not whole system.

Something like Proxifier on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bad idea. The tool you’re looking for is called `socksify` and part of the Dante suite.

[How can I socksify the whole system?](http://www.inet.no/dante/doc/faq.html#socksify_system):

> On some systems, doing the global equivalent of running a program with socksify is possible. This can be useful, but note that some programs might fail to work in a socksified environment. E.g., programs like rpm depend on a clean build-environment to get its (library) dependencies (according to Dag Wieers ).
>
> You should not attempt this unless you know what you are doing, as it is a potentially dangerous operation. The recommended way is to manually specify socksify when you start an application that you wish to add SOCKS support to. Should you however wish to try socksifying the whole system, it can be done in one of the two following ways (again, courtesy of Dag Wieers ):
>
> The most general approach is to set the `LD_PRELOAD` value in the shell startup file. This will have the same result as using the `socksify` program manually. For the Bourne shell/bash, the following lines can be added to the appropriate startup files, such as `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc`.
>
> ```
> LD_PRELOAD="libdl.so libdsocks.so"
> export LD_PRELOAD
> ```
>
> On Linux, it is also possible to add the lines below to the `/etc/ld.so.preload` file, but again, do not do this unless you understand what you are doing.
>
> ```
> libdl.so
> libdsocks.so
> ```
>
> When all applications are socksified it might sometimes be necessary to turn of socksification. This can easily be achieved (in the Bourne shell/bash) with the following command:
>
> ```
> unset LD_PRELOAD
> ```